# Featured on Meta is not showing [featured] meta articles

Tags: bug, status-completed

If you go to [Code Golf SE main](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), the only post that is listed on **Featured on Meta** is the one featured on Mother Meta. But [the site actually has two more `featured` posts on its own meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured). They were showing correctly in the said list before the brief maintenance today.

<s>Tried to check if it has hit other sites too, but couldn't (I checked SO, Math, Puzzling, Code Review but none of them had site-specific [featured](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) posts at this moment).</s> [Workspace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions) and [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) are showing their own [featured](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) posts correctly, so I'm posting this to site-specific meta as well as [Mother Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362635/419414).

Comment: [Looks like this has been fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhuI9.png)